# Why joining one thread ends up calling multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, process, pthreads

I am learning about threads and programming with threads in C on Linux.  What I understand is that joining a thread simply calls the thread and wait for it to execute just like  waiting for a child process to run. But am not sure why when am trying to join one thread, it ends up calling two threads!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *start1()
{
    printf("Hello from Thread 1\n");

}

void *start2()
{
    printf("Hello from Thread 2\n");
}

void main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;

    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,start1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,start2,NULL);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL); 
}
```

When I run the code, here is the output:

```
[root@localhost]# ./a.out 
Hello from Thread 1
Hello from Thread 2
```

I expected it to only calling the code for start1.

Comment: `join` does not _call_ a thread - there is no such thing. Rather, `join` waits for the thread to die.

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  regardless of what visual studio allows, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  they are: `int main( void )`  and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice that they both return an `int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pthread_join` function simply causes the thread that called `pthread_join` to wait until the thread it joins finishes execution. While the thread that entered `main` is waiting for thread 1 to finish execution, threads 1 and 2 can run.

The code has a race condition, however. It doesn't ever wait for thread 2 to finish. So the output can be unpredictable. For example, the thread that called `main` might return from `main` and terminate the process before thread 2 ever gets a chance to get started.

Answer (score 7):

`pthread_join` waits for a thread to exit and `pthread_create` creates **and starts** a thread regardless whether you join it or not.

In your example, there are 3 threads in a program (including the main thread). If, however, the main thread that is executing the `main` function exits before 2 additional threads, then the whole program is terminated and the additional threads might not have the chance to output anything.

Most importantly, you should remember that the order of execution of program's threads is undefined, this includes but not necessarily guarantees simultaneous execution. So in your example while you are only waiting for one additional thread from your main thread, there is no way to tell for sure whether the second additional thread will have a chance to run (and exit) while you are waiting for the first one.

If, for some reason, you only want one thread to run then you should either start only one thread (obviously :)) or employ some synchronization mechanism (such as [mutex](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) or [condition variable](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_init)) that will make the second thread wait for some condition to occur before doing it's job.

Comment: When I remove pthread_join from my code and rerun. I see no output? How do you explain that then?

Comment: @aboria. Because the main() exits before the thread functions have run.  This is why the main() must wait for the threads to exit.  The function: `pthread_join()` waits for the indicated thread to exit

Comment: @r3musn0x Ok How can i wait for one thread but not the other? Can I have such flexibility, or just not run the thread at all?

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly waits for the thread(s) to exit before the program exits
4. uses the correct signature for the `thread` functions
5. properly exits the `thread` functions
6. properly handles the function parameter for each thread function
7. does not include header files those contents are not being used

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

void *start1( void * arg)
{
    (void)arg;
    printf( "Hello from Thread 1\n" );
    pthread_exit( NULL);
}

void *start2( void* arg)
{
    (void)arg;
    printf( "Hello from Thread 2\n" );
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

int main( void )
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;

    pthread_create( &t1, NULL, start1, NULL );
    pthread_create( &t2, NULL, start2, NULL );
    pthread_join( t1, NULL ); 
    pthread_join( t2, NULL );
}
```

Comment: But the proposed code doesn't seem to answer the OPs question?